# GNU screen sessions taking very high virtual memory

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, virtual-memory

My GNU screens are taking up a lot of virtual memory. What could be the reason behind this? I have confirmed that none of them have more than 5 tabs in them. I noticed this when i got 'fork: Cannot allocate memory' error on trying to create a new tab in one of the screens. Below is htop output for the screens I have -

```
VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command        
31.0G 20.5G   788 S  0.0 16.3 31:07.33 SCREEN -dR sc1 
19.4G 15.6G     4 S  0.0 12.4  4h26:16 SCREEN -dR sc2
17.5G 12.2G     4 S  0.0  9.7  9:13.87 SCREEN -dR sc3
14.1G 11.2G     4 S  0.0  8.9 11:49.34 SCREEN -dR sc4
12.7G 11.0G    40 S  0.0  8.7  7:43.32 SCREEN -dR sc5
```

Comment: I have the same problem, still looking into it, but 1) consider ulimits, 2) htop is not perfect, I've seen it be quite wrong, top never fails, although isn't as pretty, but I've never seen it be wrong, 3) one of my guesses is the scrollback buffer, lots of buffer, a bunch of tabs... can't be gigs, but maybe it's something like that.

Answer (score 1):

As @Stu suggested in the comments, for me this error was due to a `scrollback` setting of 100,000 lines, which I guess is reasonable for many of the machines I use, but I had shared my `screen` config across devices and this value was way too much for a virtual machine with 1GB of RAM.